# MongoDB Geojson or google encoded string

Tags: mongodb, meteor, geojson

Assuming I have a collection, where on each doc I have to save a polygon. I will then need to query if current location is in or out the polygon.
My question is if should I save the polygon using the mongoDB built in geojson and queries or save the polygon as an encoded string and query it the google way.(containsLocation()).

Thanks.

Comment: You dont need to encode a GeoJson data ... you can simply record it in MongoDB ... keep it simple :)

Comment: Thanks, yes it looks 10 times simpler to save one string and not change the lat lang order, takes much less space, just I wanted to make sure that I'm not missing any advantage in terms of speed?.

Comment: It will be very fast :) don't worry

Comment: What is your purpose? Do you just want storage/retrieval of the data in question where you actually look it up by another unrelated key? Or do you actually intend to "query" the data, such as finding "near" or "within" for other geometric shapes/points? If it's just storage, then the format does not so much matter. If you **must** or would find it useful to "query", then storing the GeoJSON object as an object and not a string is the only way MongoDB can handle this. It all comes down to your intended present and future usage.

Comment: My purpose is to get the list of docs the user is inside their polygon.